# Header('Location: index.php'); не работает как исправить?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

`header('Location: index.php');` не работает.
(Отправка всех полей формы на сервер с помощью ajax jQuery).
Как исправить?
Если есть ошибка при заполнении, то нормально работает

[image]
А если успех бывает вот так:

[image]

Как можно сделать нормально? Заранее спасибо!

html код:

```
<form method="POST" id="form" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">
      Логин
      <input type="text" name="username"/>
      Пароль
      <input type="password" name="password"/>
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Войти</button>
</form>

<div id="results">вывод</div>
```

js код:

```js
function call() {
    var msg   = $('#form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login.php',
        data: msg,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        },
        error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });
}
```

php код:

```php
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Вы должны ввести имя пользователя и пароль.';
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Мы не можем найти что имя пользователя. А вы зарегистрировались?';
    } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Вы еще не активировали свою учетную запись!';
    } else {
        $login = login($username, $password);
        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Это сочетание имени пользователя или пароль неверен.';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }

}
echo output_errors($errors); 
?>
```

Comment: Сделайте телнетом запрос или просто посмотрите в хроме/фаерфоксе ответ. Скорее всего там вствляется лишний текст/пробел. И перенаправление не срабатывает.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за внимание посмотрю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замени

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

на

```
exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /index.php'>");
```

Comment: @cnofss, спасибо сработало `exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /index.php'>");
            exit();`  
вот так или нужно убрать тоже `exit();` ?

Comment: Последнее exit(); убрать, оно пустое и не имеет смысла

Comment: @cnofss, Спасибо!

Comment: Какая связь есть? VK?

Comment: решение не равнозначное. Перенаправление сохраняется в истории. Location же переписывает.

Answer (score 2):

```
header('Location: /index.php');
```

Больше ничего не должно кидаться в STDOUT, иначе некоторые браузеры (кхе-осёл-кхе) могут подумать что заголовок ошибочен.

[Для лёгкого чтения.](http://www.ourcms.info/interesting_php/3-absolute_or_relative_path.html)

Comment: @TheDoctor, я вас понял!

Comment: @KYRAN, что же ты понял, юный падаван?

Comment: @TheDoctor, Абсолютный или Относительный путь к файлам

Comment: @KYRAN, Это же ![Сарказм][1]


  [1]: http://cs607322.vk.me/v607322991/7284/mVw6REajRXo.jpg

Comment: @TheDoctor, я вас вообще не понял...

Comment: @KYRAN, видимо высокоинтеллектуальный юмор :)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2QXct.png

Comment: @nicael, Это ты к чему?